# N in a row (or column)!

Tags: code-golf, array, matrix

#### N in a row

#### Input:

The character and a 2-Dimensional array.

The array with a size of `N x N` where 1 <= `N` <= 26, it will be filled randomly like so:

`N` = 1

```
A
```

`N` = 2

```
B | A
-----
A | B
```

`N` = 3

```
A | B | C
----------
B | A | B
----------
C | A | C
```

As `N` increases by 1, so does the number of letters. A = 1, B = 2, C = 3. There will always be `N` number of each letter. 
`N` = 3, there will be 3 As... 3 Bs... 3 Cs... 
`N` = 4, there will be 4 As... 4 Bs... 4 Cs... 4 Ds... 
`N` = 5, there will be 5 As... 5 Bs... 5 Cs... 5 Ds... 5 Es...

#### Output:

The original matrix as well as a manipulated matrix where any given letter has `N` in a row (or column).

Manipulations occur by swapping two letters within the 2-D grid that are adjacent on the x or y axis. You may not swap characters over the boundaries of the array. I.E. You cannot swap Array[0][N-1] with Array[0][0]. You also may not swap characters diagonally.

#### Objective:

Your job is to pick a character `C` to solve for given `N`. Swap characters within the matrix so that there are `N` of `C` in the same row or column.

#### Examples:

`N` = 3, `C` = A

```
A | B | C
----------
B | A | B
----------
C | A | C
```

Swap array[0][0] (A) with array[1][0] (B)
resulting in

```
B | A | C
----------
B | A | B
----------
C | A | C
```

Complete

`N` = 4, `C` = B

```
A | B | C | D
--------------
B | D | B | A
--------------
D | A | C | C
--------------
A | C | B | D
```

swap array[1][0] (B) with array[1][1] (D)

```
A | D | C | D
--------------
B | B | B | A
--------------
D | A | C | C
--------------
A | C | B | D
```

swap array[2][3] (B) with array[3][3] (D)

```
A | D | C | D
--------------
B | B | B | A
--------------
D | A | C | C
--------------
A | C | D | B
```

swap array[3][3] (B) with array[3][2] (C)

```
A | D | C | D
--------------
B | B | B | A
--------------
D | A | C | B
--------------
A | C | D | C
```

swap array[3][2] (B) with array[3][1] (A)

```
A | D | C | D
--------------
B | B | B | B
--------------
D | A | C | A
--------------
A | C | D | C
```

Complete!

Any letter can be chosen to solve for. As this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) the shortest code wins!

Have Fun and Good Luck!

Comment: Using those swaps I can generate any permutation of the matrix, so doesn't this just reduce to identifying the distinct elements and printing the matrix in which each fills a row?

Comment: @PeterTaylor The idea would be for you to input a random permutation where 1<=n<=26. Then solve for each problem. There are times where the grid will be solved on input, but you would need to handle every case.

Comment: My point is that it can be "solved" without doing any work. You were already pointed at http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/10002/20283 in a comment on your previous question. I think that you're falling into the same trap again, but this time even worse, with the result that the specification is unusably vague.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Your code will prove the validity of the assignment. The instructions are clear, playing devil's advocate and poking holes in the question is silly when the code and output provided will prove any negatives.

Comment: So you need to output the matrix after each step? Or the coordinates of the swaps? Does the program need to end the first time it meets the criteria?

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 270 bytes

```python
from random import*
e=lambda s,n:all(sum(map(ord,l))!=n*65for l in s)
R,C,d=randint,choice,[-1,1]
def w(a):
 print a;n=len(a);
 while e(a,n)and e(zip(*a),n):
    if n==2:x,y,w,z=0,0,0,1
    else:x,y=R(1,n-2),R(1,n-2);w,z=x+C(d),y+C(d)
    a[y][x],a[z][w]=a[z][w],a[y][x]
 print a
```

Always chooses `A` as character to complete a row/col. Performs random swaps until goal is reached.

Accepts the matrix as list of lists, usage for testing:

```python
A="""ADCD
BBBA
DACC
ACDB"""
a=[[c for c in l] for l in A.split('\n')]
w(a)
```

Comment: A random solution. Nice

Comment: @jacksonecac Normally not my style but i thought it is quite helpful here. At first i did random swaps until any character reached the goal, but then i read in your description to pick one, so i did.

Answer (score -1):

## R, <s>41</s> 40 bytes

This answer provides valid output, although it does not follow the algorithm suggested. Since a limitless number of swapping manipulations are permitted, restrictions on what manipulations are allowed (e.g. the diagonal restriction) are irrelevant, as any permutation of the matrix can be arrived at through a (possibly large) number of swaps. So, I've bypassed the "switching around" part of the matrix manipulation and just went straight to outputting a solved matrix.

Anonymous function that takes a matrix as input, and returns a list of the original matrix and the "solved" matrix.

```
function(m)list(m,array(sort(m),dim(m)))
```

Example input:

```
matrix(c("A","B","A","C","C","B","A","C","B"),3)
```

That is,

> [,1] [,2] [,3]
>
> [1,] "A"  "C"  "A"
>
> [2,] "B"  "C"  "C"
>
> [3,] "A"  "B"  "B"

Gives the following output:

```
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "C"  "A" 
[2,] "B"  "C"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "B"  "B" 

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
[2,] "A"  "B"  "C" 
[3,] "A"  "B"  "C"
```

While we're at it, here's a function to generate possible input matrices:

```
make_matrix = function(N) matrix(sample(rep(LETTERS[1:N], N)), N)
```

This function takes the first `N` letters of the alphabet, repeated `N` times (i.e. `N*N` characters) and randomly samples from them. The characters are then arranged into a matrix with `N` rows (and, implicitly, `N` columns).

Examples:

```
make_matrix(1)
     [,1]
[1,] "A" 
> make_matrix(3)
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] "C"  "B"  "C" 
[2,] "C"  "A"  "B" 
[3,] "A"  "B"  "A"
```

And used with our function above (named `f`):

```
> f(make_matrix(10))
[[1]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] "J"  "C"  "D"  "G"  "E"  "C"  "H"  "G"  "I"  "J"  
 [2,] "C"  "D"  "A"  "C"  "H"  "A"  "A"  "E"  "H"  "I"  
 [3,] "C"  "B"  "E"  "G"  "C"  "F"  "J"  "A"  "H"  "J"  
 [4,] "I"  "E"  "F"  "I"  "B"  "G"  "E"  "F"  "F"  "C"  
 [5,] "H"  "I"  "F"  "D"  "B"  "G"  "H"  "A"  "J"  "H"  
 [6,] "J"  "E"  "D"  "J"  "A"  "D"  "B"  "D"  "G"  "B"  
 [7,] "D"  "B"  "E"  "A"  "G"  "H"  "C"  "C"  "J"  "B"  
 [8,] "H"  "D"  "I"  "J"  "B"  "I"  "I"  "F"  "E"  "I"  
 [9,] "G"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "J"  "E"  "B"  "A"  "E"  "D"  
[10,] "H"  "G"  "A"  "B"  "D"  "I"  "C"  "G"  "F"  "F"  

[[2]]
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [2,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [3,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [4,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [5,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [6,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [7,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [8,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
 [9,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  
[10,] "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"
```

Comment: This doesn't follow the OP's instructions.

Comment: I wrote this: function super(Object) it calculates any answer to any problem you can ever think of.

Comment: @jacksonecac I'm sorry if my answer upset you. I'm afraid I am having difficulty in understanding why I am being downvoted. Could you explain in what way my answer doesn't meet your specifications? Is it because the matrix is not explicitly manipulated in the "swap array[0][0] with array[0][1]" sense?

Comment: You haven't provided any code, simply function names that don't do anything. You are assuming the output of all of your functions. The idea of code-golf is to provide the shortest possible code to achieve the solution to the given problem.

Comment: `function(m)list(m,array(sort(m),dim(m)))` **is** code. This defines an anonymous function in R. I'm not assuming the output of my functions, I pasted them from the R console after I ran my code! Do you mean that you want a full program, rather than a function? Your original post doesn't specify this, nor does it provide any indication as to what format the input is in, or how you would like the output. In the absence of this information, I wrote the shortest code I could.

Comment: sorting the array is not swapping two values, it is performing a sorting algorithm, which is not the intention of this question.

Comment: @jacksonecac Ah, so the question is based on a [non-observable requirement](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges/10002#10002)? What if the `sort` function implements multiple swaps internally (e.g. bubble sort)? Would that satisfy the requirement? (Note that I don't know what R's `sort` actually does under the hood, this is a hypothetical question.)

Comment: So you submitted an answer to clear requirements without knowing what your code is doing? "Manipulations occur by swapping two letters within the 2-D grid that are adjacent on the x or y axis."

Comment: I know perfectly what my code is doing. When given an input matrix, as your question states, it returns an output matrix that meets your requirements. Your other requirements are unclear. How do you know if the manipulations occurred in the manner you wanted? What if my language does not allow direct modification in place, and I need to create copies of the object and change one cell at a time? Does that count as swapping or not? The requirements are not at all clear.